# How do you use a RewriteRule?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've used RewriteRules before, but usually only copying and altering from a CMS framework, so I've not had the fun of writing them myself from scratch. However, using my basic knowledge of them, I've put together the following .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^post/(.*)$ post.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tag/(.*)$ tag.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^more/(.*)$ subpage.php?id=$1 [L]
```

In case I've done something really wrong, the effect I'm aiming for is:

```
http://example.com/post/testpost
    is rewritten as
http://example.com/post.php?id=testpost
```

however, I cannot for the life of me get the id to show up. The server redirect to the correct page (post.php), and all seems to be fine, but I cannot call the id from $_GET. I've run a var_dump of $_GET, and the array is empty, so I know I'm not just misspelling it in my php. If I manually visit the post.php page as the RewriteRule should output, the variable shows up fine. The code on post.php is:

```
<?php
    //this function performs sanitisation and returns the HTML page contents
    echo PostViewer($_GET['id']);

    //this is just for testing purposes
    var_dump($_GET);
?>
```

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "QSA" after "L" eg. [L, QSA]

what's happening is your RewriteRule is using the GET and then not re-appending it for your script to use. QSA = Query String Append. Does exactly what it says on the tin.

Comment: Thanks; I've made your changes and am just having a little issue getting apache to recognise my .htaccess changes. I'm going to let it reboot then I'll give it a go!

Comment: It should work straight away. Make sure you have mod_rewrite enabled in your config. Try clearing browser caches too.

Comment: mod_rewrite enabled, and browser caching shouldn't be an issue (I've checked they're cleared, and they're not switched on); but there seems to be something very wrong with my server. Whatever I do to the htaccess file (including deleting it), the server still seems to think I'm using the version posted above. It's making testing a little strenuous. I might wait until I'm back in the office and can put it all in a Vagrant box.

Comment: Well, I've just tested it in a box, and it works perfectly with your additions, thanks! It would seem my localhost server is broken for some reason, so I'm going to trash it and rebuild it from scratch.